# Walkthrough: Adding ASP.NET AJAX Scripting to an MVC Project

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, msdn

I'm trying to learn more about asp.net ajax. But when I followed ([this short tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381533.aspx#Y800), the functionalities are not working like they supposed to be. If you click on the actionlink, an ajax call should be executed and return a string on the same page. In my project he renders a new page and returns a string. I follow the tutorial 2 times and could not find my problem. Many Thanks if anyone can help

rendering code html when the page opens

```
<p> Page Rendered: 15:00:09 </p>
<span id="status">No Status</span>
<br>
<a href="/Home/GetStatus" data-ajax-update="#status" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax="true">Update Status</a>
```

code html when i click the link (this is in a new page)

```
<body>Status OK at 15:04:12</body>
```

you can find the program code in the link from the tutorial, because I copy pasted it.
Only thing that changes is the view engine (razor)

Comment: how can we help you if you don't post your code here? Post the HTML your code generates. Post _only_ the relevant parts please

Answer (score 0):

i wouldn't even mess with the MSFT ajax stuff.  [jquery](http://jquery.com) is the industry standard but there are other javascript libraries such as [Moo](http://mootools.net/) and [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/).  i can't imagine what benefits the msft library would have over these other ones.